# get Data using angularJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, html

I'm trying to get Data in HTML Table using angularJS, I've splitted the project in 3 parts :

1- Main Part :  main.html : which load html Table file and also the Java script(angularJS) (Main.html)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Student's List</div>
    <div ng-include="'Student_list.html'">
</div>
<script src= "../js/ngMain.js"></script>
```

2- Html Table : it's Table html tag (Student_list.html)

```
<table class="table table-borAdherentdered table-hover" id="stdlst">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Birth's Date</th>
                <th>Class</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="std in students">
                    <td>{{std.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{std.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{std.Email}}</td>
                    <td>{{std.BoD}}</td>
                    <td>{{std.Class}}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

3- JS File : load data From mySQL (ngMain.js)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.GetStudent=function() {
        $scope.students=[];
        $http.post("Main.php",{'ScriptName':'GetData','ScriptParam':'student'+"|"+'Id'+";"+'Name'+";"+'Email'+";"+'BoD'+";"+'Class',"DataTypeResult":'string'})
       .success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
        $scope.students=data;
        console.log("Get Student List succesfully");
      });
    }

});
```

The php script (Main.php) it's working  I have tested using REST app with no problem.

My Problem here :
Is that I don't get any Data, only Table Header (BTW :in student Table there is a lot of records) ?
Any idea What 's missing ? or if I m doing it wrong please correct me .

Thanks.
/Koul

Comment: What do you see if you console.log(data) in the success handler?

Comment: Where you are calling $scope.GetStudent();

<table class="table table-borAdherentdered table-hover" id="stdlst" data-ng-init="GetStudent()">

Then check are you getting any data inside success function.

Comment: you should share console.log(data) output with us

Comment: That's the problem it does not go thru the function, how to tell to table tag to execute the function GetStudent ?

Comment: use data-ng-init = <table class="table table-borAdherentdered table-hover" id="stdlst" data-ng-init="GetStudent()">

Comment: Thanks vignesh , it's going now thru the function BUT unfortunately got errors on my function:  Parsing Error

Comment: Should I return json format or normal php array result from GetStudent function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your function, $scope.GetStudent, is never called in your controller, thus the data for your table is never fetched.
If $scope.students stays empty, you will see only the headers of your table.

To debug these kinds of issues, it is good practice to watch the network tab in your developer tools of the browser you're using, just to see if your data provider (Main.php) is being called.
In this case I would suspect that it isn't since there is no call to your $scope.GetStudent function in your provided code.

To call the function when the script is loaded, just add a call ($scope.GetStudent()) in your controller just after your function definition.

Example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.GetStudent=function() {
        $scope.students=[];
        $http.post("Main.php",{'ScriptName':'GetData','ScriptParam':'student'+"|"+'Id'+";"+'Name'+";"+'Email'+";"+'BoD'+";"+'Class',"DataTypeResult":'string'})
        .success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            $scope.students=data;
            console.log("Get Student List succesfully");
        });
    }
    $scope.GetStudent();
});
```

Regards,

Sem

Comment: Without calling the function that get's your data, you'll have no data :)

Take a look at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

There you will find how to use routes and views to conditionally load your table and controller, so the data is only displayed and retrieved whenever you need it.

Comment: did you read my answer below, please have a look and tell me what do you think ?

Comment: the situation is simple I think that I don't need routing or multiview or filtering here specially at this stage . I m just asking how to get data from mysql when Table html is loaded  not in JS script itself not in the main html file. The idea using 3 parts on my project is also for to get Forms and other Tables .

Comment: Using ng-init would be possible on the table, to load the students when the table is loaded. Or you could adjust the method to hide / show the table and include a call to your GetStudents function there.

Comment: In answer of your question if you should use php array of json as response, use json, js / angular understands that natively and will process it correctly.

Comment: Also see: https://jsfiddle.net/kx2fe08w/
Your students weren't loaded because there was nog controller defined in your html.

Comment: it's working now . it's going thru the function. the data result from mysql should be in json format ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93515/discussion-between-koul-and-semvdwal).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code you posted is incomplete. 
There are no ng-app and ng-controller at all and the GetStudent function is never called.

However here there is a working fiddler with mock data that I think will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ds7hryn5/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="panel panel-primary" >
  <div class="panel-heading">Student's List</div>
  <table class="table table-borAdherentdered table-hover" id="stdlst" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Birth's Date</th>
            <th>Class</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="std in students">
                <td>{{std.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{std.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{std.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{std.BoD}}</td>
                <td>{{std.Class}}</td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>

   </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.GetStudent=function() {
    $scope.students=[{
        Id:4,
        Name:'Name1',
        Email:'name1@eee.it',
        BoD:'bod1',
        Class:'class'
    },{
        Id:5,
        Name:'Name2',
        Email:'name2@eee.it',
        BoD:'bod2',
        Class:'class'
    },{
        Id:6,
        Name:'Name3',
        Email:'name3@eee.it',
        BoD:'bod3',
        Class:'class'
    }];

  }
  $scope.GetStudent();

}]);
```

Comment: I don't want to call the the GetStudent() in JS or in the Main html and I wanted only to Call when the Table html file is loaded.

Comment: see this update : https://jsfiddle.net/ds7hryn5/3/ and please tell me why data is not loaded

Comment: If you want to call the GetStudent() only when the table html is loaded I think that you have to create a new Directive with your table as template and its own controller calling the GetStudent function.
For further info see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive